# fazer um link através de um <a> para um popup

Tags: html

Olá

eu gostava que alguem me ajuda-se a dizer como é que eu posso criar um `<a>` e através dele levar para um pop-up criado num site diferente do meu.

ate agora tenho este codigo:

```html
 <h5 id="denuncia">Caso saiba de algum caso de violencia doméstica
  <a href="https://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/eu-reporter-cm?ref=geral_MenuHeader" class="denunciastyle" target="_blank">denuncie aqui</a>
  </h5>
```

e eu queria que através desse link levasse para este popup:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e não para o site que depois tem um botão para o popup, agradeço a quem me tentar ajudar.

Comment: Cara está difícil de entender o que vc quer.... Vc precisa que ao clicar entrar na página abra um PopUp? Ou na página tem um link que quando vc clica deve abrir um PopUp?

Comment: @hugocsl acho que ele quer um modal com um iframe, e no iframe o src de outro site mostrado no href do <a> acima

Comment: basicamente ao clicar no <a> abra o site já com o pop-up aberto.

Comment: @Sam Nesse caso acho que seria melhor colocar um btn por cima do iframe, algo que a Google considera como BlackHat, pq acredito que ele não consegue do site dele inserir um link dentro do iframe...

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem o que você precisa, você não quer sair da pagina para exibir a pagina do link?

Comment: pode fazer isso usando `window.open`

Comment: não sei como me explicar melhor basicamente é só isso que precisava saber, eu tentei por no href do <a> o link do outro site mas não abre o pop-up pois para abrir esse pop-up e preciso clicar no botão que está no site e o que eu quero é evitar o click e sim levar direto para o pop-up

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você quer abrir o modal de outro site dentro do seu site, acredito que só de para fazer isso, se o outro site for seu também, ai você pode criar uma rota para retornar apenas o modal e chamar ela no seu site com JQuery....

Comment: @AlissonMarqui é isso sim que eu quero fazer! mas preciso de ter acesso tbm ao outro site? nao há um http do pop-up? que posso colocar como link?

Comment: @DavidMv Pelo que vi do site em questão (https://www.cmjornal.pt) ele não tem um link para o pop-up apenas, ele é carregado junto com a pagina completa...

Comment: @AlissonMarqui OK! obrigado pela ajuda! de todos inclusive!

Comment: @DavidMv Qual o url que acessa esse pop-pup?

Comment: @MagicHat [link](https://www.cmjornal.pt/mais-cm/eu-reporter-cm?ref=geral_MenuHeader) esse é o site principal e ao clicar no botão verd irá levar para o pop-up

Comment: O que você realmente precisa é de um modal com os componentes organizados dentro. usa bootstrap no projeto?